# permalink error when modifying sanitize_title_with_dashes function

Tags: permalinks, language

By default, wordpress remove accents and weird characters to generate `post_name` in wp_posts table. This post_name is used when we change the permalink structure to `/%postname%/` or some similar structures. In my language, i don't want to remove and replace many characters as it distorts the meaning.

I have change the `sanitize_title_with_dashes` function in wp-includes/formatting to:

> function sanitize_title_with_dashes($title) {

```
$title = strip_tags($title);`
// Preserve escaped octets.
$title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
// Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
$title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
// Restore octets.
$title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);
```

/* comment out this code block

```
if (seems_utf8($title)) {
    if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
        $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
    }
    $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
}

$title = strtolower($title);
```

*/

```
$title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
$title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
```

// comment out  $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);

```
$title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
$title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
$title = trim($title, '-');

return $title;
```

}

The post_name is correctly generated for all characters in my language, for example `http://1.todaytravels.info` in the latest post, the url is very good, but wordpress simply does not find the post (it says `not found`). I guess i need to change something in permalink structure so that WP query to the correct post.

Anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you want to alter the URI here? SEO optimization?

An URI has a limited number of allowed chars, defined in an RFC. That's the reason WordPress uses `utf8_uri_encode` to generate a permalink based on the posttitle.

You can find more information in this stackoverflow question:
[Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

### EDIT

I've checked the `wp_insert_post()` function in `wp-includes/post.php`, which generates a new post in the database based on the submitted `$_POST` array. There you have a call to `sanitize_post()` on line `2487` and also a call to `sanitize_title()` on line `2548`. You should check both functions.

Another option could be, that an attached filter to one of these sanitize functions are fired in the background. You could remove any filters with the function [`remove_all_filters()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_all_filters)

**For example:**

`remove_all_filters('sanitize_title', 99);`

Comment: Ya, i want to keep all valid characters untouched in the title. These are valid language characters, it is definitely valid for url (i see many websites used that too). I want not to use the utf8_uri_encode, but maybe some more changes are needed so that WP query to the correct post

Comment: Maybe `utf8_uri_encode ` is also used in another rewrite rule function. That function direct wordress to post content, but i'm not sure where to find it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @PamApple I've edited my answer. Maybe this brings you a bit further.

Comment: Hi Rofflox, in the sanitize_title() function (located in `formatting.php`), i commented out the line `remove_accents` because this changes the characters. After doing this, i can open my posts and firefox browser indicates correct characters, but in the page source (and post_name in wp_posts table) there are a lot of junks (% ss characters). Then i comment out the `utf8_uri_encode`, the post_name field now show correct characters, but i can no longer open the post (`Not Found`). I can't find any relation of the problem with `sanitize_post` because the post does not relate to the url.

Comment: I guess it means that `sanitize_title` is not the culprit of the `not found` problem. The problem is in `utf8_uri_encode` that need to be comment out somewhere else. I'm not sure any other function also use `utf8_uri_encode`

Comment: I just realized that is not due to `utf8_uri_encode`. From the toscho's suggestion, i see that the junks in html source code is actually what communicate with server. So i found way to remove those junks by adding `urlencode` in the corresponding functions in link-template.php file. Now i have resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Non-ASCII characters in URLs have to be encoded. Use [`rawurlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) to do that.

Example: a slug `öüä` has to be encoded as `%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%A4`.
You can still enter `öüä` into the address bar, the browser will send the encoded URL to the server.
`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will be `7%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%A4`, `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` will be `öüä`.

[image]

Do not edit WordPress files, use a filter instead. You cannot run updates anymore otherwise.
In my plugin [Germanix](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin/blob/master/germanix_url.php) I hook into `'sanitize_title'`, take the second argument (the raw title) and change that. You should do the same.

Comment: Hi toscho, your plugin does not work for me because it removes non-english character. Or maybe there is something i need to change. I have resolved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Of course it doesn’t. :) It just shows you how to hook into WordPress without changing a core file.